# jQuery load / unload?

Tags: jquery

So I was wondering how you would do this.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="001">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="002">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="003">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

And my jQuery works like this :

```
jQuery('.001').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).load('pages/001.html');
});
```

So what I would like is too add a line saying that if i click on another div (002 for example) to unload / go back to divs 001 state.

How would you achieve this ?

I was thinking of varing the contant at the beginning of the jQuery code and reloading it before each load, but I don't know if this is optimal.

Any ideas / tips ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to store the state somewhere and then restore it. Manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your loaded pages does not contain so much complex data, such as images, videos, etc. Use hide() and show() instead of loading html inside a div and loosing the previous state. If you use it for different purpose, create another div, make it invisible, and store your previous state content inside it, Thus you can swap whenever you want in that case.

Comment: Yes actually it contains tons of images, hence the reason I want to .load it to not make loading time of the page too long.

Comment: I do understand that concern, what I was trying to point out is, if you plan to bring different heavy data to your divs, what I have suggested wouldn't be the best solution, but if I were you I would give it a try, and create empty invisible divs, and when you load something into ".001/.002/.003", first store the current content in the invisible div, then load the new content into the div. In this way, when you need to revert to the previous state, you can easily, get it from your invisible div.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, and than just loading a empty file into on another click. Thanks !